# Are there duplicate/almost same verses in scripture?

Tags: scripture, verse

For example, from Bhagavad Gita:

> yada yada hi dharmasya
> glanir bhavati bharata
> abhyutthanam adharmasya
> tadatmanam srjamy aham
>
> **Whenever and wherever there is a decline in religious practice, O descendant of Bharata, and a predominant rise of irreligion—at that time I descend Myself.**
>
> paritranaya sadhunam
> vinasaya ca duskrtam
> dharma-samsthapanarthaya
> sambhavami yuge yuge
>
> **In order to deliver the pious and to annihilate the miscreants, as well as to reestablish the principles of religion, I advent Myself millennium after millennium.**

In this case, the similar verses are from the same scripture. Are there verses in one scripture that are the same or almost the same as verses from another scripture?

Comment: There are similar verses, if I remember correctly or vaguely, in *Shiva geeta* as well

Comment: If you mean overlapping then Skanda and Padma; Srimad Bhagavatam and Vishnu Purāṇa, Devi Bhagavatam and Brahmavaivarta Purāṇa; Vayu and Brahmanda Purāṇa

Answer (score 1):

> Are there verses in one scripture that are the same or almost the same
> as verses from another scripture?

Yes, Here is one such instance.

*Almost Same Shlokas From Padma and Narada Puranas:-*

> *अथ विष्णुर्महातेजा महेशमिदमब्रवीत् ।। सर्वैर्नमस्यते यस्तु सर्वैरेव समर्च्यते ।। ७९-१९६ ।। हूयतं सर्वयज्ञेषु स भवान्किम्‌ जपिष्यति ।।
> रचितांजलयः सर्वे त्वामेवैकमुपासिते ।। ७९-१९७ ।। स भवान्देवदेवेशः कस्मै
> विरचितांजलिः ।। नमस्कारादिपुण्यानां फलदस्त्वं महेश्वरर ।। ७९-१९८ ।। तव
> कः फलदो वंद्यः को वा त्वत्तोऽधिको वद ।। तच्छ्रुत्वा शंकरः प्राह
> देवदेवं जनार्दनम् ।। ७९-१९९ ।। ध्याये न किंचिद्गोविंदनमस्ये ह न किंचन
> ।। किंतु नास्तिकजंतूनां प्रवृत्त्यर्थमिदं मया ।। ७९-२00 ।। दर्शनीयं
> हरे चैतदन्यथा पापकारिणः ।। तस्माल्लोकोपकारार्थमिदं सर्वं कृतं मया ।।
> ७९-२0१ ।।*

**~ Narada Purana Purva Bhaga Chapter 79**

> अथविष्णुर्महातेजा महेशमिदमब्रवीत् । सर्वैर्नमस्यते यस्तु सर्वैरेव
> समर्च्यते २४४। हूयते सर्वयज्ञेषु स भवान्किं जपिष्यति । रचितांजलयः
> सर्वे त्वामेवैकमुपासते २४५। स भवान्देवदेवेश कस्मै वा रचितांजलि ।
> नमस्कारादि पुण्यानां फलदस्त्वं महेश्वर २४६। तव कः फलदो वंद्यः को वा
> त्वत्तोधिको वद । शंकर उवाच- ध्याये न किंचिद्गोविंद न नमस्येह किंचन
> २४७। नोपास्ये कंचन हरे न जपिष्येह किंचन । किंतु नास्तिकजंतूनां
> प्रवृत्त्यर्थमिदं मया २४८। दर्शनीयं हरे ते स्युरन्यथा पापकारिणः ।
> तस्माल्लोकोपकारार्थमिदं सर्वं कृतं मया २४९।

**~ Padma Purana, Patala Khanda , Chapter 114**